# Click on *.url File Type offers Download for Original Content Instead of Opening OC in the Browser's Web View

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, office-integration, links

We are using a SharePoint Online library that includes shortcuts (*.url) to original files (pdf; docx; pptx; xlsx; etc.) within the same library based on *.url file extensions. Since recently, when we attempt to open such a link, our browser offers to download the original file, instead of opening the original file in our browsers' webview. I am wondering what is causing this change of behavior. Settings > Advanced Settings > Opening Documents in the Browser is still set to server default, which is opening them in the browser. And Site Settings > Site Collection Features > Open Documents in Client Applications by Default is still deactivated, right as before. It should be noted, though, that opening the original content, i.e. not via their links, opens them in the web view, just as desired.

Best regards and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Which browser you are using? Have you changed the browser settings before?

Comment: Hi! I am using Chrome, but I have also tried it for Internet Explorer and Firefox. None of them opens the content in its web view. Merely Internet Explorer and Firefox offer the local opening of the content next to the regular download option. Our browser settings, except for Firefox, are managed by our organization. Yet, I hesitate of blaming the browser, as the behavior along all browser instances is the same.